# Mongoose save function doesn't execute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I am trying to save my model into the my db in MongoDB. This code actually works if I were to go through this code path when running the node server, however when I try to use mocha to test saving the model it doesn't get saved anymore. I have verified that the connection to mongodb is fine. Thia is the output:

before regular save
after regular save

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

This is the test I am running.

```
var app = require('./helpers/app');
var User = require('../models/user');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var should = require('should');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoUrl = require('./../config.js').mongoUri
var clearDB  = require('mocha-mongoose')(MongoUrl);
var testuser = {
    username:"admin1",
    password:"password",
    email:"test@gmail.com",
    firstname:"testfirst",
    lastname:"testlast",
    phonenumber:"4151231234"
};

describe("Routing", function() {
describe("Creating an account", function() {

    //To run before each test. DB Clean up is implicitly done after each test.
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        if (mongoose.connection.db) {
            return done();
        }
        mongoose.connect(dbURI, done);
    });

    it('User: Creating an account2', function(done){
        var newUser = new User({
            username: "testusername",
            email: "test1@gmail.com",
            password: "password",
            phoneNumber: "12312312",
            firstname: "testfirst",
            lastname: "testlast"
        });
        console.log("before regular save");
        newUser.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("testerror: " + err);
            }
            console.log("in regular save");
        });
        console.log("after regular save");
        User.find({}, function(err, docs){
          if (err) return done(err);

          console.log(docs);

          docs.length.should.equal(1);
          done();
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: What does your Mocha output look like? Does the test finish or does it timeout? That would be helpful to know. It looks like the test could just be timing out before the save function is ever fired.

Comment: based on the output its like the save call is just skipped since the log statement afterwards prints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Model#save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) is an async function so you have to wait until it calls its callback before you can expect to be able to find the saved doc with a `Model.find` call.

So put the `find` check inside the `save` callback:

```
it('User: Creating an account2', function(done){
    var newUser = new User({
        username: "testusername",
        email: "test1@gmail.com",
        password: "password",
        phoneNumber: "12312312",
        firstname: "testfirst",
        lastname: "testlast"
    });
    console.log("before regular save");
    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("testerror: " + err);                
            return done(err);
        }
        console.log("in regular save");
        console.log("after regular save");
        User.find({}, function(err, docs){
          if (err) return done(err);

          console.log(docs);

          docs.length.should.equal(1);
          done();
        });
    });
});
```